# setting up cakephp on opensuse

Tags: cakephp, permissions, opensuse

I am pretty new to linux and trying to setup cakephp on opensuse 12.1. I did as told on the cakephp website(blog tutorial) and most probably encountering some permission issues. I slapped the cakephp folder in /srv/www/htdocs and then tried to access it using localhost/cakephp where it says

```
Access forbidden!
You don't have permission to access the requested object. It is either read-protected or not readable by the server.
If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.
Error 403
```

But as i check for permissions I get

```
Suse:/srv # ls -lR shows sankalp as owner for all the files down the tree.

sankalp@Suse:/srv/www/htdocs> whoami
sankalp
sankalp@Suse:/srv/www/htdocs> ls -l
total 108
drwxrwxrwx  6 sankalp users  4096 Jun 27 12:44 cakephp
-rw-r--r--  1 sankalp users 73728 Jul  6 10:41 das
-rwxrwxrwx  1 sankalp  root    302 Mar 13  2006 favicon.ico
-rwxrwxrwx  1 sankalp  root     26 Jun 28 19:04 whoami.php
```

Neither can I access whoami.php while favicon.ico gets displayed in the browser.What am I doing wrong here when I have given 777 to the user.

Answer (score 0):

You should assign the permission as 777 to /app/tmp directory.

```
chmod -R 777 /srv/www/htdocs/yourApp/app/tmp
```

Hope it will work for you. Please ask if it is not working for you.

Comment: I tried your suggestion also but this would not be of any use as i earlier mentioned that I cant even access the /srv/www/htdocs/cakephp in the browser using localhost/cakephp.Someone told me to check who am  i running my server(apache) as but I am not sure of that.